# Volume of a Parallelpiped, Homework Check

Tags: linear-algebra

I've not sure if I am doing these types of questions properly, so I figured I would ask here. Find the volume of the parallelpiped with sides u, v, and w:

$u = 3, 1, 2$

$v = 4, 5, 1$

$w = 1, 2, 4$

(v x w) = 
$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 5 &1\\
1 &2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$

= $\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 1\\
2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$
-$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 1\\
1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$
+$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & 5\\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$

$= |18, -15, 3|$

$= u(v x w) = -54 + 15 -6$

$= -33$

(Pretty sure I did this wrong, as you can't get a negative volume)

---

$u = 2, -6, 2$

$v = 0, 4, -2$

$w = 2, 2, -4$

(v x w) = 
$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4 &-2\\
2 &2 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$

= $\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
4 & -2\\
2 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$
-$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2\\
2 & -4
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$
+$\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4\\
2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$

$= |-12, 4, -8|$

$= u(v x w) = -26 + 24 + 16

$= 66$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be careful with your notation, stick $i,j,k$ in where appropriate. i.e.

$(a,b,c)\times (d,c,e)=\begin{vmatrix} i & j & k\\ a & b & c\\ d & e &f \end{vmatrix}
= i \begin{vmatrix} b & c\\ e & f\end{vmatrix} - j \begin{vmatrix} a & c\\ d & f\end{vmatrix} + k \begin{vmatrix} a & b\\ d & e\end{vmatrix}$

As for the sign error notice that $A\cdot (B\times C)=A\cdot (-(C\times B))=-A\cdot (C\times B)$ so when you are interpreting this as a volume make sure to take the absolute value.

In the first part it looks to me like you dotted $-u$ with $v\times w$ not $u$.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to just write a comment but I might as well make it an answer. Your work seems correct for both save for somehow you introduced a negative sign in the first one where there wasn't a negative sign. I.e. that $3\cdot 18=54 $ not $-54 $ that is all, you have what appears to be the correct answer but wrong sign.